# scheme function to filter a list

Tags: scheme

Write a scheme function that returns a list containing all elements of a given 
list that satisfy a given predicate eg. (lambda (x) (< x 5)) '(3 9 5 8 2 4 7) => '(3 2 4)
Any hints how to begin about this ?

Comment: do you know how to define a function?

Comment: (define sum
  (lambda (a b c)
    (+ a b c)))

Comment: Write that lambda inside a `filter` and you're done

Comment: do you know how to define a function that accepts two arguments -- a predicate and a list -- and returns the first element of that list?

Comment: If you don't know how to recurse over lists, read about that. If you're not familiar with `if`, `cond`, `car`, `cons`, and `cdr`, read about them. If using functions as first-class values ("higher-order functions") are a mystery to you, read about that, too. (As you may have noticed, it is very difficult to tell where you should begin without any hints about what you already know.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are creating `filter`.

```
(define (filter included? lst)
  ...)
```

You need to check if the argument has elements and if the first element is to be included or not. Including would involve `cons`-ing the first element to the recursing with the `cdr` with the same predicate while not including would not include consing but the exact same thing as the tail in a conse situation.

```
(filter odd? '(3 4)) 
; ==> (cons 3 (filter odd? '(4)))

(filter odd? '(4)) 
; ==> (filter odd? '())

(filter odd? '()) 
; ==> '()
```

Putting them together shows that `(filter odd? '(3 4))` should produce the result of `(cons 3 '())`

Here is a skeleton of what I would have done:

```
(define (filter included? lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) <??>)
        ((included? (car lst)) <??>) ; since it is not null? it has to have at least one element
        (else <??>)))                ; neither null? nor included? => skip
```